# Updating Items from a Checkbox in Laravel

Tags: jquery, html, laravel

I have multiple checkboxes for which the values are retrieved from the database. Every checkbox has a select/dropdown which the user can change to `low, medium, high` and update the value. My problem is that the update is not working and the dropdown/select is only returning the first item in the options. The user should be able to change multiple items at one time.

**View**

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('allergies.update', ['id'=>Auth::user()->id]) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    @foreach($userallergens as $aller)
        <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="ua_id" value="{{$aller->ua_id}}">
        <select name="tolerance[]">
            <option value="Low">Low</option>
            <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
            <option value="High">High</option>
        </select>
        <label style="color:black" name="allergen[]" value="{{$aller->ua_id}}">
            {{ $aller->allergen_name}}
        </label>
    @endforeach
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

public function update2(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($request['tolerance']); $j++) {
        $user = UserAllergen::where('ua_id', $request['ua_id'])
            ->where('user_id', $user)
            ->update(['tolerance_level' => $request['tolerance'][$j]]);
    }

    return redirect()->route('user.profile', compact('id', 'user'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, hope it will help you.

```
public function update2(Request $request, $id){
     $user = Auth::user()->id;
     $data = $request->all();
     $tolerances = $data['tolerance'];
     foreach($tolerances as $tolerance)
     {
         $this->updateData($data['ua_id'], $user, $tolerance);
     }

     return redirect()->route('user.profile', compact('id', 'user'));
}

public function updateData($ua_id, $user, $tolerance_level)
{
    UserAllergen::updateOrCreate(
        ['ua_id' => $ua_id, 'user_id' => $user],
        [
            'tolerance_level'          => $tolerance_level
        ]
    );
}
```

Comment: It is working, but there are still bugs. It is updating, but the first item won't update unless there is only one item.

Comment: Yes it working, but just first item on the list won't update

Answer (score 0):

Add **multiple** attribute to select multiple items.

```
<select name="tolerance[]" multiple>
```